# AX 2012R2: Lookup query takes too long, lookup never opens

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a AX2012R2 CU6 (build&client 6.2.1000.1437, kernel 6.2.1000.5268) with the following problem:

On AP>Journals>Invoices>Invoice Journal>lines (form LedgerJournalTransVendInvoice), when I select Vendor as *Account type* and then activate the lookup on the *Account* field, AX freezes for a couple minutes and when it recovers, the lookup is closed/never opened. This happens every time when account type vendor, other account types work just fine.

I debugged this to LedgerJournalEngine.accountNumLookup() --> VendTable.lookupVendor line

`formSegmentedEntryControl.performFormLookup(formRun);`

The above process takes up the time.

Any ideas before I hire an exorcist?

Comment: What query is it executing? Trace it and tune it.

Comment: It's basic AX:

SELECT FIRSTFAST AccountNum, Party 
 FROM VendTable(VendTable) ORDER BY VendTable.AccountNum ASC 
 JOIN Name, City, Locator, State, ZipCode, CountryRegionId, NameAlias 
 FROM DirPartyLookupGridView(DirPartyLookupGridView) 
 ON VendTable.Party = DirPartyLookupGridView.Party 
 AND ((((DirPartyLookupGridView.AddressValidFrom <= 2015-12-15T14:29:27) && 
         (DirPartyLookupGridView.AddressValidTo >= 2015-12-15T14:29:27))))

Comment: Furthermore: I run the view DIRPARTYLOOKUPGRIDVIEW from SQL Server, first 1000 rows. Took three minutes.

In a non-R2 environment, five seconds.

Comment: Can you post the query and execution plan then? Here or on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Posted a link below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a known KB for this for R3, look for it on [Lifecycle services](https://lcs.dynamics.com)

> KB 3086961 Performance issue of VendorLookup on the volume data,
>   during the GFM Bugbash 6/11 took over 30 minutes

Even though the fix is for R3 it should be easy to backport as the changes are described as

> The root cause seemed to be the DirPartyLookupGridView, which had
>   around 14 joins on views and tables. This view is used in many places
>   and hence seemed to have grown quite a lot over time.
>
> The changes in the hotfix remove the view and add only the required
>   datasources - dirpartytable and logisticsaddress to the
>   VendTableLookup form.
>
> The custtableLookup is not using the view and using custom datasource
>   joins instead, so no changes there.

Try implementing that change and see what happens.

I'm not sure this will fix your issue as in your execution plan the only operation that seems really expensive is the sort operator which needs to spill to tempdb (you might need more memory to solve that) but the changes in the datasource could have the effect of removing the sort operator from the execution plan as the data may be sorted by an index.

Comment: This seems to be it. Would you know how I can get the info about the changes, so I can make them manually and try it out?

Comment: I added a link in the answer. You can search there and there is a "view changes" button.

Comment: Alas, the "view changes" is useless. I created a LCS incident to get the changes in XPO. We'll see, but this really seeme to be the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, this was it. The culprit was view called DirPartyLookupGridView that had grown too large and slow, so in R3 Microsoft removed it as a datasource from form VendTableLookup and added DirPartyTable etc as datasources. Dropped opening the lookup from three minutes to half a second after I made the changes. Another esoteric AX problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the SQL Server chose the wrong query plan.

First check that you have not disabled any indexes on the involved tables, then do a synchronize on them.

If still a problem, then to run a [STATISTICS UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) on the involved tables (including the tables in the view).

Comment: Made a project that included all the tables and views affected, found no disabled indexes, synchronized. No effect.

SQL Server maintenance plan rebuilds all indexes and updates all statistics nightly.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Use the SQL you provided in a SQL Server Query window then show execution plan etc. I guess you used SQL tracer or this answer to get it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33927010/4509

Comment: The SQL script, execution plan and its XML are in Gdrive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Qfc-HE9_U1ZnBfRmhMZmRLWWs

Comment: I suspect the `OR (T2.PARTITION#2 IS NULL)` etc. makes the query slow. This may be a kernel error, that is solved in a newer version of AX. Try searching the issue in LCS or apply a kernel update.I did not  understand the XML execution plan.